# Spacing inside a div

Tags: css, image, html, position

After long hours I am literally one div away from finishing my first html practice, and I wouldn´t have been able to do so without the support of this awesome community.

My only problem right now is to avoid the cluster-fluster that is my social media div. I need the links to be slighlty smaller in size, and for then to be next to the imgs (with a space ofc) and right now they are a bit off.

Also the newsletter part with its respective img is being clingy to the social one and doesn´t want to give it space to breath.

Any ideas would be deeply aprecciated!
Best Wishes

CSS CODE:

```
#contactUs{
position: absolute;
margin: 20px 0 0 700px;
}


   #social p{
color: #404040;
font-family: 'Quattrocento Sans', sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
top: 5px;
padding: 0 0 0 20px;
line-height: 23px
    }

#social img{
float: left;
}

#social{
position: absolute;
top: 15px;
}

#news{
color: #404040;
font-family: 'Quattrocento Sans', sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
bottom: 10px;
}
```

And the HTML:

```
    <div id="contactUs">
        <h4 id="title4">GET IN TOUCH WITH US</h4>
        <img src="imgs/social.png">
        <div id="social">
            <p><a href="#">Facebook</a></p>
            <p><a href="#">Twitter</a></p>
            <p><a href="#">Google+</a></p>
        </div>

        <h4 id="news">NEWSLETTER SIGNUP</h4>
        <img src="imgs/email.png">
    </div>
```

It is worth noting that this div is right to 2 others which are behaving as they should right now. Also I cannot use %.

Comment: Before asking a new question, you should first accept all the previous answers to your previous questions that apparently helped you.

Comment: I had no idea how to close, I never used this thanks for telling, everyone got their due credit.

Comment: Awesome! Perhaps you could provide a jsfiddle to help us see what your problem is more easily?

Comment: Alright, I will see how to do it first I am literally new to this. And thanks again

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/VWLZ7/ took the liberty of making one for you. However, I'm still confused as to what you want to do. You can put a display:inline on your social div and that will put a space between it and the image, but can you try to provide a graphical example of what you're trying to achieve visually? Perhaps it just needs a rewrite, because even with the problems you are having, it still looks...I dunno, strange (yeah, real vague, sorry).

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/MXcvL/  here it is, I don´t know why the social part got so deformed, I think is is because the icons are not showing in this "fiddle" (funny word btw) but that is basically it, also I just noticed the recent tweets is bit out of line if I compare it to the other.

Comment: Thanks Hiigaran! As of now I can´t post images but I will cook something in paint right now.

Comment: Don't worry. Your updated fiddle helps me get an idea of your layout. I'll try and see what I can do.

Comment: Error: http://i62.tinypic.com/anxx0j.png

Comment: NoError:http://i58.tinypic.com/fp8p00.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your original code was rife with issues, so it turned out to be easier to just create some new code instead.

One of the problems I immediately saw was your incorrect usage of the ID attribute. The ID attribute is meant to be unique, meaning that you cannot give more than one object on your page the same ID. If you want to group multiple objects together, use the class attribute instead. Keep in mind that in your CSS, while an ID is denoted as `#IDName`, a class is denoted at `.ClassName`. As a beginner, you might find it easier to just work exclusively with classes instead, but as your pages become bigger and more complex, you will find that one might be more useful than the other.

Now, onto your actual code. I've tried to recreate the layout of the screenshot your provided as best I can, but it's missing some styling, such as font colours. I'm going to assume you can fix that yourself, so I can focus on explaining the more important things.

```
<footer>
    <div class="footColumn">
        <h4>24 HOUR CUSTOMER SERVICE</h4>
        <div class="inner">
            <img src="imgs/icon-phone.png" class="left">
            <p class="offset">512-943-1069</p>
            <p class="offset">512-943-1068</p>
        </div>
        <div class="inner">
            <img src="imgs/icon-email.png" class="left">
            <p class="offset"><a href="#">info@WTPcom</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="inner">
            <img src="imgs/icon-address.png" class="left">
            <p class="offset">1341 Oakmound Drive</p>
            <p class="offset">Chicago, IL 60609</p>
        </div>  
    </div>
    <div class="footColumn">
        <h4>RECENT TWEETS</h4>
        <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
        <p><a href="#">- 1 day ago</a></p>
        <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p>
        <p><a href="#">- 2 days ago</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="footColumn">
        <h4>GET IN TOUCH WITH US</h4>
        <img src="imgs/social.png" class="left">
        <p class="offset"><a href="#">Facebook</a></p>
        <p class="offset"><a href="#">Twitter</a></p>
        <p class="offset"><a href="#">Google+</a></p>
        <h4 class="news">NEWSLETTER SIGNUP</h4>
        <img src="imgs/email.png">
    </div>
</footer>
```

CSS:

```
footer{
    font-size:0;
}
.footColumn{
    display:inline-block;
    width:33%;
    font-size:12px;
    vertical-align:top;
}
.footColumn h4{
    font-size:14px;
}
.offset{
    padding:0px 0px 0px 30px;
    margin:0px 0px 10px;
}
.inner{
    padding:10px 0;
}
.left{
    float:left;
}
```

[Here's a Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FLZ95/)

From here, you should be able to touch up on the lesser styles, but let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I wasn't allowed to use % or footer yet for this practice but as you said I can tweak it! And thanks for the tips ;D